# WebRTC channelMessage not recieving first message

Tags: javascript, webrtc, chat

When sending a message using WebRTC sendDirectlyToAll, the message is never recieved the first time, but every time after that.
I've stripped the code down to a very simple state now, but it's still the same. Anyone got a clue about why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```js
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
  localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
  remoteVideosEl: 'remoteVideos',
  autoRequestMedia: false,
  media: {
    video: true,
    audio: false
  },
  localVideo: {
    autoplay: true,
    mirror: true,
    muted: true
  }
});

$("#chat-send-button").on("click", function (e) {
  sendMessage();
});

function sendMessage() {
  console.log("sendMessage");
  const chatMessage = $("#chat-message-input");
  webrtc.sendDirectlyToAll(
    "chat",
    "info", {
      "chatmessage": chatMessage.val()
    }
  )
  chatMessage.val("");
}

webrtc.on("channelMessage", function (peer, channel, data) {
  console.log(peer);
  console.log(channel);
  console.log("data", data);
  $("#chat-message-container").text(data.payload.chatmessage);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need for the WebRTC connection to be established before allowing the user to send a message - do you make use of the `readyToCall` event described in the documentation https://github.com/SimpleWebRTC/SimpleWebRTC#3-tell-it-to-join-a-room-when-ready

(a link to an editable runable code snippet might help)